# OMS Update Management schedule fails with Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024401F

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics

In OMS I created schedule to update Windows Server 2012R2 servers (in Update Managemend solution > Update Deployments) but it looks like this jobs fails every time.

In Azure portal > Automation Accounts > "my-automation" > Jobs" there are failed jobs: 
[image]

This is exception info from the job details:

`Exception
Failed to scan for missing updates with exception Exception calling "Search" with "1" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024401F" (Failed to scan for missing updates with exception Exception calling "Search" with "1" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024401F"`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description for that error is:

0x8024401F - WU_E_PT_HTTP_STATUS_SERVER_ERROR

"Same as HTTP status 500 – An error internal to the server prevented fulfilling the request."
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You will also likely be getting an error when trying to manually search for an install updates.

Do you have these machines configured to use a WSUS server and is it functioning?

Do you have a firewall on your network or on these machines that are blocking or interfering with your connection to the update server?

Judging by the number of failed jobs, this seems to be something in your environment that is common to all of these machines.

Comment: There is no firewall and servers depend on WSUS. I'll try to install updates manually and we'll se if it helps for futer updates.

Comment: You were right. Manual Windows Update throws exception so I guess this is different issue.